# AMP-List is showing for PC, Tablet, and other Phones but not my Pixel 2

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

Anyone have any idea why AMP-LIST appears perfectly fine in most devices, PC, any browser yet when I view it on my Pixel 2 in Chrome it does not work.

It works on my Pixel 2 in Edge and Firefox but in chrome the AMP-List is not pulling.

Has anyone seen this before?

What do you need from me to help diagnose?

Comment: Can you post your code for the page/amp-list? Maybe even a link if you have it live?

Comment: Apparently, it had to do with me not placing the entire link. Instead of https://example.com/file/location.json I just had /file/location.json. Which interestingly made it work on some devices but not others. Though putting the full URL fixed the issue.